# Shopify - Liquid | List vendors based on Product Type

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to display a list of Vendors based on product type, so for example:

If I have 1'000 products with a Product_type of "CBD" I want to display a list of all vendors of products based on product Type.

How can I achieve this? I have tried to display vendors based on collection but it's not really working.

Comment: what issue when you tried the `collection.all_vendors`?